# Electron - Open file from menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a button in my electron app that says 'open file', and when you click on it the open file dialog box comes up and I am able to select a file.

Although, how am I able to open the 'open file dialog' box when I click a menu item from the apps toolbar?

This is my label in a submenu for the toolbar menu:

```
label: 'Open',
accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+O'
```

I want to do something like:

```
label: 'Open',
accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+O',
role: 'open'
```

But there is no such role as 'open'.

How can I implement an on click event that opens the open file dialog box?

**Main.js open file section:**

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain
const dialog = require('electron').dialog

ipc.on('open-file-dialog', function (event) {
  dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ['openFile', 'openDirectory']
  }, function (files) {
    if (files) event.sender.send('selected-file', files)
  })
})
```

**index.js:**

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer
const selectDirBtn = document.getElementById('open')

selectDirBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    ipc.send('open-file-dialog')
})

ipc.on('selected-file', function (event, path) {
    document.getElementById('selected-file').innerHTML = `&#9658; ${path}`
    document.getElementById('selected-file2').innerHTML = `${path}`
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Prime: Use IPC to communicate between the main and render process

Here is an example:

```js
// main.js 

const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, dialog, ipcMain } = require('electron')
// wait until the app is ready before you can do anything 
app.whenReady().then(function() {
  // setting up the main window object 

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    webPreferences: {
      // devTools: true,
      nodeIntegration: true
    },
    show: false,
  })

  // setting up the menu with just two items 
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'Menu',
      submenu: [
        {
           label:'Open File',
           accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+O',
           // this is the main bit hijack the click event 
           click() {
              // construct the select file dialog 
              dialog.showOpenDialog({
                properties: ['openFile']
              })
              .then(function(fileObj) {
                 // the fileObj has two props 
                 if (!fileObj.canceled) {
                   mainWindow.webContents.send('FILE_OPEN', fileObj.filePaths)
                 }
              })
  // should always handle the error yourself, later Electron release might crash if you don't 
              .catch(function(err) {
                 console.error(err)  
              })
           } 
       },
       {
           label:'Exit',
           click() {
              app.quit()
           } 
         }
      ]
    }
  ])
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
  // now run it 
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
  mainWindow.show()
})
```

Not going to show the `index.html` you should know what to do, just include the `render.js` into the HTML document.

Now the render.js

```js
// render.js 
const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron')
ipcRenderer.on('FILE_OPEN', (event, args) => {
  // here the args will be the fileObj.filePaths array 
  // do whatever you need to do with it 
  console.log('got FILE_OPEN', event, args)
})
```

This was tested run on Electron 9.X

Answer (score 1):

I had two buttons, a non-visible input file and visible styled button.

```
<input type="file" id="fileId" style="display:none;" />
<button class="btn-lg btn-primary center-block" type="button"
    id="btnLoadFile">Load File</button>
```

In the js, I set the styled button click event to trigger the input file click event.

```
document.getElementById('btnLoadFile').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('fileId').click();
});
```

Then I have an on change event listener for the input file element, that does some operation with the file.

```
document.getElementById('fileId').addEventListener('change', function(e){
    //use the file here
    var files = e.target.files;
    var f = files[0]; {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var name = f.name;
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think this addresses OP's question about making the menu bar's `open` function work.